# Can turbulence happen at landing?

Tags: turbulence

If we  exclude wake turbulence, can this [turbulence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8Wm9xCrTH8) happen at low altitude, for example at landing or take off?
How many meters plane drop in turbulence, if that happen at landing, plane will crash or this type of turbulence don´t happen at low altitude?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3Sr2F_xxLo) I find airliner drop during take off.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  They are called [microbursts](https://www.weather.gov/bmx/outreach_microbursts#:%7E:text=Microbursts,%2C%20can%20be%20life%2Dthreatening.), and are to be avoided for obvious reasons.

How many meters of sink, what will happen, etc. depends on the aircraft type and severity.

Comment: So if we avoid bad weather then no worry for turbulence at landing?

Comment: You can't say that. Microbursts can happen on good days as well. Here is a detailed write up of a recent glider crash due to a microburst  https://chessintheair.com/invisible-microburst-kills-expert-glider-pilot/

Comment: @EnginKurutepe, I wouldn't call winds gusting 40-50mph a "good day".  The glider crash you linked to was a tragic event, but let's not insinuate that it wasn't preventable or relates to hazards directly and commonly applicable to airline travelers.  Airline pilots brief and practice go-around procedures for low level wind shear.  Not saying it couldn't happen, but please don't stoke up more fear without adding some perspective or context.

Comment: @MichaelHall I find example where airliner is hit by microburst at take off, added to my post.

Comment: @user207141, interesting, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MichaelHall if read the report the prevailing wind was 9 kts straight down the runway as reported by the eyewitness pilot who landed 5mins after the accident. The 40-50mph wind you mention was the microburst that caused the glider to fall out of the sky. Not trying to stroke any fear here. The question was if avoiding bad weather is enough to avoid turbulence and the answer is not categorically no. I wasn't aware the context was commercial aviation.